# Multiple content creation on a single page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to allow the user to create 10 content nodes on a single page instead of clicking on "add a new node each" time. This is just to save the users time when he/she wants to create 80 nodes at one time.

Is there any such module which supports this functionality or will I need to write a module for my own?

Answer (score 2):

The first module I can think of (reading your description) is [Nodes](http://drupal.org/project/nodes), which is described using the following text:

> The Nodes module allows a user to edit multiple nodes at once. The module provides a simple table layout, similar to Editview, so that multiple nodes can be seen at once, and quickly and easily edited.
>
> Changes to a node are done using AJAX like calls, so that as each field is edited, it is changed on the live version of the node. This means that any edits that take place are not submitted in bulk, and therefore any problems that arise as editing takes place can be dealt with on a field by field basis.

Unfortunately, the project doesn't have any public release.

[Editview](http://drupal.org/project/editview), referred in the description, is a Views plugin that allows to create a view where all the listed nodes are editable.

Other modules you can find on drupal.org are:

- [Mass Content Creator](http://drupal.org/project/mass_create)
- [Node Repeat](http://drupal.org/project/node_repeat), which allows to create duplicates/clones of nodes
- [Multiple Node Add](http://drupal.org/project/multi_node_add)

Answer (score 0):

[Slickgrid](https://www.drupal.org/project/slickgrid) can be used for this purpose.